# Dynamic Variable name that increment with each loop of a foreach

Tags: powershell

I have a variable that has **X** amount of .opt configuration files under a specific path.

```cs
$optfiles = gci C:\"Program Files"\tivoli\tsm\baclient\ -Recurse -Include *.opt | Select-Object Name
```

What I want to do next is run a `foreach` against ObjectPropertyName of those .opt files and have the output for each file name into its own separate variable.

```
foreach ($result in $optfiles) {
    # XXX
}
```

My question how can I take the code above and put into a separate variable for each .opt file?

Comment: Each file name **is** in own separate variable already because `$optfiles` is an [array](https://pwrshell.net/back-to-basics-arrays/). Refer them as  `$optfiles[0]`, `$optfiles[1]`, … with index up to `$($optfiles.Count -1)`

Comment: Also, trying to creating variables on the fly for something like that is an anti-pattern and should be avoided.

Comment: I agree. it is best to use the array elements like JosefZ said. even if you create variables on the fly, how would you know what they are for future reference? you would have to store it in an array and call it again like array elements. why go to all that trouble?

Comment: We have over 100+ production servers in our environment, so I thought about creating script which will be listed all data movers per proxy server then print them in dynamic switch as login option. (still thinking about conception)